# Flutter: Keyboard automatically closing `AccordionSection`

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield, accordion

## Description:

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter app using the accordion package version 2.6.0. I have a TextField inside an AccordionSection, and when I try to input text into the TextField, the keyboard opens and immediately closes the AccordionSection.

## Code Snippet:

### Profil view

```dart
class MyView extends StatelessWidget {                      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Accordion(
      scaleWhenAnimating: false,
      openAndCloseAnimation: true,
      sectionOpeningHapticFeedback: SectionHapticFeedback.heavy,
      sectionClosingHapticFeedback: SectionHapticFeedback.light,
      children: [
        AccordionSection(
          headerBackgroundColor: AppTheme.colors.lightbeige,
          contentBorderColor: AppTheme.colors.lightbeige,
          contentBackgroundColor: AppTheme.colors.lightbeige,
          rightIcon: Icon(Icons.expand_more,
              color:
                  AppTheme.colors.getColorForUserType(isStudent)),
          header: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 8, bottom: 8),
            child: Text(
              "Supprimer mon profil",
              style: AppTheme.text.labelStyle.copyWith(),
            ),
          ),
          content: CustomSection(
            isStudent: isStudent,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:frontend/theme/theme.dart';

class CustomSection extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isStudent;
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

  DeleteProfileSection({super.key, required this.isStudent});

  @override
  State<DeleteProfileSection> createState() => _DeleteProfileSectionState();
}

class _CustomSectionState extends State<CustomSection> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
                style: AppTheme.text.latoDarkGray14fw400,
                "Tu es sûr(e) de vouloir supprimer ton compte ? Cette action est irréversible, elle te déconnectera et toutes tes données seront supprimées."),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Mot de passe *',
                  style: AppTheme.text.labelStyle,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                TextField(
                  autocorrect: false,
                  autofillHints: const [AutofillHints.password],
                  controller: controller,
                  focusNode: widget._focusNode,
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Mot de passe',
                    hintStyle: AppTheme.text.hintStyle,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: AppTheme.colors.white,
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                        minHeight: 40, minWidth: 150, maxWidth: 300),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('Annuler',
                        style: AppTheme.text.latoWhiteFs14Fw400.copyWith(
                            color: AppTheme.colors
                                .getColorForUserType(widget.isStudent)))),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor:
                        AppTheme.colors.getColorForUserType(widget.isStudent),
                    minimumSize: const Size(150, 40),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    'Supprimer mon compte',
                    style: AppTheme.text.latoWhiteFs14Fw400,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Environment:

Flutter version: 3.16.2
Accordion package version: 2.6.0

## Expected Behavior:

I expect the AccordionSection to remain open while I'm entering text in the TextField. The keyboard should not trigger the closing of the section.

## Actual Behavior:

The AccordionSection closes when the keyboard is opened, disrupting the user experience.

## Additional Information:

I've tried exploring the documentation of the accordion package, but I couldn't find any specific information regarding this issue. Any guidance or suggestions on how to prevent the AccordionSection from closing when the keyboard is opened would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!